# String date to time in PHP - strtotime "loses hours"

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

I have the behavior which is cofusing me:
1. I got rom request some string date "02.07.2014".
2. Trying to convert it to timestamp

```
strtotime($search->date_from)
```

it returns me **1404244800**. Assumig that my bug is here, I'm trying to check what I get on this url http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm and found the **Tue, 01 Jul 2014 20:00:00 GMT**

It's almost what I need , excluding that 4 hours are lost: it's very bad for me and unexpected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of php script, put

```
date_default_timezone_set("YourTimeZone");
```

YourTimeZone can be one of this: 
    [Timezone](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works. But does it mean that decision is not universal ?

Comment: Auto detect timezone is a php issue. You need to use javascript to send location to php. PHP Frameworks use a "Locale Pattern", with \DateTime Object, it's a advanced use of timezones to easy the pain of detecting timezone for i18n websites. If you need internazionalization you should try a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `strtotime` function relies on the system timezone, unless you set it otherwise.
You can set the timezone using [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), example:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
strtotime(...);
```

Also, see the [timezone reference](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this link instead and it will determine your LOCAL time. http://www.epochconverter.com

The 4 hours that you are losing is most-likely due to the fact that you do not have your timezone set. You can either do this in the php.ini file or in your .php file.

In your .php file do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); // if you live in USA on east coast
```

// For a list of possible arguments, go here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Hope this helps.